# Children's ghost story in 1980s whose character names started A, B, C

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a creepy programme we watched when I was at primary school, possibly about a haunted house. The main characters were children. This would have been early 1980s in the UK. We watched it at school for some reason, then it must have been repeated as I saw it again on TV on holiday. It left a strong emotional impression but I've never worked out how to find out what it was.

The one thing I do remember is someone at school pointing out that the character names started A, B, C (e.g. Alan, Betty, Claire). These characters were probably the children.

It was definitely live action as I've a vague memory of seeing child actors. I remember finding it creepy, so I'm pretty sure there was something fantastical/supernatural about it. My emotional memory of it is a bit like watching *The Twilight Zone* (albeit one for eight year olds!), where there's a weird, unusual concept, which caught my attention.

Comment: Was this live action, cartoon, puppets or something else?

Comment: Also do you remember anything that was science fictional or fantastical about this?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Well, if the house seemed credibly haunted... :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots True but they're not even sure if it was haunted to begin with,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this may be [*Dark Towers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Towers) part of the look and read series.

First episode here:

This was on in the 80's and shown in UK schools and does indeed have ghosts in it and I remember it been creepy as well.

At least among the main cast, the names do not follow the alphabetical model:

> - Juliet Waley as Tracey Brown
> - Gary Russell as Lord Edward Dark
> - David Collings as Lord Dark / The Friendly Ghost
> - Christopher Biggins as Benger
> - Harry Jones as Bunce
> - Juliet Hammond (credited as Juliet Hammond-Hill) as Miss Hawk
> - Peter Mayhew as The Tall Knight

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I swapped out your "not sure" part of the answer with some text of the names of the characters showing that it does not match.

Comment: Oooh, not sure but maybe. Episode 1 does feel a bit familiar (and what a cast! Not to mention 5th Doctor style music), but it doesn't fit the alphabetic name thing. Though there's every chance I've misremembered that as being from something else. It's definitely the right kind of thing though, especially as it was shown in schools. When I get a chance I'll watch the other episodes to see if it fits.

Comment: @Mourek: With all apologies to Dreamwalker for bringing it up, if this turns out to not be the correct answer, you can always remove acceptance by clicking on the checkmark again.

Comment: @fuzzyboos I presumed he watched them all and realised.  It was quite dark for a kids program,